# How to find and match each elements of a list on each sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file including some sentences. I used polyglot for Named Entity Recognition and stored all detected entities in a list. Now I want to check if in each sentence any or pair of entities exist, show that for me.

Here what I did:

```
from polyglot.text import Text

file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
test = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='fa')

list_entity = []
for sent in test.sentences:
    #print(sent[:10], "\n")
    for entity in test.entities:
       list_entity.append(entity)

for i in range(len(test)):
    m = test.entities[i]
    n = test.words[m.start: m.end] # it shows only word not tag
    if str(n).split('.')[-1] in test: # if each entities exist in each sentence
         print(n)
```

It gives me an empty list.

Input:

```
 sentence1: Bill Gate is the founder of Microsoft.
 sentence2: Trump is the president of USA.
```

Expected output:

```
Bill Gate, Microsoft
Trump, USA
```

Output of list_entity:

```
I-PER(['Trump']), I-LOC(['USA'])
```

How to check if `I-PER(['Trump'])`, `I-LOC(['USA'])` is in first sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you were adding the whole text file input to the entities list. 
`entities` can only be called by each sentence in the polyglot object.

```py
from polyglot.text import Text
file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
file = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='fa')

list_entity = []
for sentence in file.sentences:
    for entity in sentence.entities:
        #print(entity)
        list_entity.append(entity)

print(list_entity)
```

Now you don't have an empty list.

---

As for your problem with identifying the identity terms,

I have not found a way to generate an entity by hand, so the following simply checks if there are entities with the same term. A Chunk can have multiple strings inside, so we can go through them iteratively.

```py
from polyglot.text import Text
file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
file = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='ar')

def check_sentence(entities_list, sentence): ## Check if string terms 
    for term in entities_list:               ## are in any of the entities
        ## Compare each Chunk in the list to each Chunk 
        ## object  in the sentence and see if there's any matches.
        if any(any(entityTerm == term for entityTerm in entityObject) 
               for entityObject in sentence.entities):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

sentence_number = 1 # Which sentence to check
sentence = file.sentences[sentence_number]
entity_terms = ["Bill", 
                "Gates"]

if check_sentence(entity_terms, sentence):
    print("Entity Terms " + str(entity_terms) +  
          " are in the sentence. '" + str(sentence)+ "'")
else:
    print("Sentence '" + str(sentence) + 
          "' doesn't contain terms" + str(entity_terms ))
```

Once you find a way to generate arbitrary entities all you'll have to do is stop popping the term from the sentence checker so you can do type comparison as well.

---

If you just want to match the list of entities in the file against a specific sentence, then this should do the trick:

```py
from polyglot.text import Text
file = open('input_raw.txt', 'r')
input_file = file.read()
file = Text(input_file, hint_language_code='fa')

def return_match(entities_list, sentence): ## Check if and which chunks
    matches = []                           ## are in the sentence
    for term in entities_list:                  
        ## Check each list in each Chunk object 
        ## and see if there's any matches.
        for entity in sentence.entities:
            if entity == term:
                for word in entity:
                    matches.append(word)
    return matches

def return_list_of_entities(file):
    list_entity = []
    for sentence in file.sentences:
        for entity in sentence.entities:
            list_entity.append(entity)
    return list_entity

list_entity = return_list_of_entities(file)
sentence_number = 1 # Which sentence to check
sentence = file.sentences[sentence_number]
match = return_match(list_entity, sentence)

if match:
    print("Entity Term " + str(match) +  
          " is in the sentence. '" + str(sentence)+ "'")
else:
    print("Sentence '" + str(sentence) + 
          "' doesn't contain any of the terms" + str(list_entity))
```

Comment: The `entity_terms` is a list, while the `sentence` is a string, even you convert it to string, but does not match to `entity_term`. The problem is with the format that `polyglot`  generate.

Comment: This is the output that I got:  `Sentence 'اشرف غنی رئیس جمهور افغانستان است.' doesn't contain terms['اشرف غنی', 'افغانستان']`, if you see the word in terms are surrounded by single quotes like in English it is `Áshraf Ghani'` => `'اشرف غنی'`. Would you tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: sentence is in fact not a string, it is a `polyglot.Sentence` object. A `polyglot.Sentence` object has an `entities` property that returns a list of `polyglot.Chunk` objects, which define your entities.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for matching of `entities with sentences`, both are the same `polyglot objects`. Even I change the `entity_terms` to the `list_entity`, both are not in the same format and does not match each other. How to solve it? since long times, I tried but could not find the solution.

Comment: You need to make sure the entity terms are being identified at all by polyglot before you can run the term comparison -  I cannot run that sentence through my polyglot since it is not identifying the language dataset. What's the output for `print(sentence.entities)`?

Comment: If you look at the function, I call for `entity[0]` which **pops the `string` term from the entity `Chunk` object for the comparison** with `entity_terms` string list. This is a valid comparison so far, you just need to figure out how to write mock `Chunks` with the entity objects you want for better accuracy.

Comment: The output of the `sentence.entities : ['Ashraf', 'Ghani'] \n ['Afghanistan'] ...` This one is correct that only print the text. But you also `append` it to the `list_entity`, while I print that, it prints with `tags` such as, `I-PER(['Ashraf', 'Ghani'])....`

Comment: I see. It gets like that because it is a compound name, unlike your example where you just use "Trump". I've updated the code to match that case.

Comment: Thanks what you wrote is working. But the main thing is that I extracted the `Named Entities` from the `sentences`. I have to match the `entities` with the `sentences`, but you matched with a list `entity_terms`. How to deal with the list object of polyglot entities.

Comment: If you can see in the above code, first I create an entity list `list_entity` from the input file. Now I want to check if any of the `entities` in each `sentences` of that file. Without user defines the list. If you kindly help me in this part. It will be a pleasure for us.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concern, but it makes more sense why you had that list around. I've added another example with what I think is what you want.

Comment: Dear Mr. Lucasgcb, I solved it by using `create_entity = file.entities[0]` \n `only_entity = file.words[create_entity.start : create_entity.end]`. Now, this gives me the exact word without its `tag`.  Just one problem arises here, that I did this for only one entity, we I have several entities, how to write a loop that based on `len(sentence)` and `len(entities)` should extract the entities. If you kindly give me some concept. I am new in programming. Thank you

Comment: `file` doesn't return the entities in either of our code so I'm not sure what else you've done. As for the loop, I recommend studying the code I made or closing this question and asking/searching a different one.

Comment: I've updated the new code one last time to reflect the output from the question, with the words extracted. Please try to keep questions as minute as possible so it is easier for everyone; if you have difficulties with polyglot then try asking smaller questions about polyglot and if you have difficulties with loops try asking smaller questions about loops (rather than both at the same time ahah).

Comment: Thank you very much. Just the last question, in your second code, `sentence_number = 0` is given manually, how it should go to all the sentences?

Comment: Something like `for sentence in file.sentences` block would loop through all sentence objects in the list `file.sentences`. Code into the `for` block would be run for each.

Comment: Your changes in the code are fine, just instead of two entities that match in one sentence, it repeatedly prints the matched entities? like `('Ashraf, 'Kabul', 'Kabul')`

Comment: It returns all entities that match, so the logic for matching and unwrapping entities is there. All you have to do is adjust the `return_match` function code. Open another question if you want help with that.

Comment: I asked another question, please if you have time to help me. Thank you